# Isogeny inducing isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I'm reading The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, by J. Silvermann, 2nd edition. I don't understand the following proof.

[image: It is from chapter 7, section 7]

Why is this homomorphism between $E_{1}[m] \to E_{2}[m]$ a isomorphism?

I know that if $\phi$ is separable, then $\#ker\phi = deg(\phi)$. Then, I have that the kernel no contains points of order m (Remembering that (m,deg($\phi))=1$. So, we are done.

But, $\phi$ can have inseparable part. So I don't understand how I can conclude that it will be always an isomorphism.

Comment: I would guess that a non-trivial inseparable part means that $\deg(\phi)$ is divisible by $\mathrm{char}(k)$.

Comment: $E_{1}[m] \to E_{2}[m]$ is a group isomorphism because both groups are of order $m^2$  and the order of the kernel is coprime to $m$ (so it is injective and for sets of same finite size injective implies bijective). The $G_{\overline{K}/K}$ module isomorphism is because defined over $K$ means the $G_{\overline{K}/K}$ action commutes with the isogenies

Comment: @reuns the kernel is coprime to $m$ when the kernel is equal to degree of the isogeny(separable case). Why can I state the same in general? I don't know the order of the kernel.

Comment: The size of the kernel is $\deg_s(\phi)$ which always divide $\deg(\phi)$ (think to the corresponding function field extensions : $K(E_1)/K(E_1)^{\ker(\phi)}/K(\phi^*(E_2))$ where $K(E_1)^{\ker(\phi)}$ is the subfield of functions on $E_1$ invariant under $P \mapsto P+Q, Q \in \ker(\phi)$ then $\deg(\phi) \overset{def}= [K(E_1):K(\phi^*(E_2))]$ and $|\ker(\phi)| = \deg_s(\phi) = [K(E_1):K(E_1)^{\ker(\phi)}]$)

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that the size of the kernel is $\deg_{s}(\phi)$

Comment: The isogeny theorem (that you don't need here) is that $\psi \phi = [\deg(\phi)]$ for some (unique) dual isogeny. It is not hard to show $\psi$ exists as an homomorphism on torsion points, showing it is given by algebraic equations is a little harder (you may want to use the invariant differential)